# I am working on API and getting result in JSON in android

Tags: java, android, json

I don't know how to store same type multiple value in list or something kind of ... please help.. I am working on this json.

```
[
   {
      "Message":"Number of pincode(s) found:10",
      "Status":"Success",
      "PostOffice":[
         {
            "Name":"Bhonker",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Budhi Bawal",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Chauharpur",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Gwalda",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Jhiwana",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Joria",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Maseet",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Mehesra",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Milakpur Turk",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Branch Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tijara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         },
         {
            "Name":"Tapukara",
            "Description":null,
            "BranchType":"Sub Post Office",
            "DeliveryStatus":"Delivery",
            "Circle":"Rajasthan",
            "District":"Alwar",
            "Division":"Alwar",
            "Region":"Jaipur HQ",
            "Block":"Tizara",
            "State":"Rajasthan",
            "Country":"India",
            "Pincode":"301707"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: If you are using Kotlin Try out this Plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-  makes life so simple

Answer (score 0):

You can create [POJO](http://jsonschema2pojo.org/) from JSON.
& Please properly format your question before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson):

> It can also be used to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java
> object. Gson can work with arbitrary Java objects including
> pre-existing objects that you do not have source-code of.